Project reference in ASP.NET MVC
I have a custom validation class I created as shown here PIC1.
I use a 3-tier architecture in ASP.NET MVC. My presentation layer depends on the business logic layer, and the business logic layer depends on the data access layer.
IMG2
Now my problem is that I can't access this custom class that I wrote in the data access layer - how could I access it?
I have tried to change the projects references but nothing is working

Presumably for your layers to reference each other you would have had to add them to each other as project references, correct?  Why can't that same process be repeated for your new project?  It's not clear to me where you're actually stuck.  Can you update the question to demonstrate what you've tried?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

In a 3-Tier Architecture, the data access layer is responsible for connecting to the database to send and receive data.
The business logic layer is responsible for managing the logic applied to the data sent to or received from the database.
The presentation layer is responsible for displaying the required data to the user.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
